# How to create a Target via command line

Tags: ios, xcode, shell

I have read about some document about creating build via Terminal, but my requirement is that I  have need to create target via terminal using script.

Can anyone have idea on that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with AppleScript:

```
make new target with properties {name:"My new target"}
```

but this is just the beginning. Drag the Xcode.app onto the ScriptEditor to get a description of the possible commands.

Comment: It gives error make: *** No rule to make target `new'.  Stop.

Comment: This is not a shell script. Try `osascript -e 'tell application "Xcode" to make new target with properties {name:"My new target"}'`.

Comment: What i am doing that go to my project path in terminal and write as u mention:"make new target with properties {name:"Test2"}"

Comment: Now i am getting execution error: The variable target is not defined. (-2753)

Comment: I am doing -->        osascript -e 'make new target with properties {name:"Mynewtarget"}'

Comment: Note: AppleScript is like a remote control for macOS apps. If you want to create a new target, you must open the corresponding project in Xcode first. The best way is to write a complete script with the ScriptEditor first.

Comment: Actually I am very new to this so can u please explain  what command i can use in AppleScript

Comment: The command `make new target` is an AppleScript command, for instance. But you must send more commands to Xcode for an useful script, e.g. open the project from a file, make the target, add files to the target, and so on. Create a new target in Xcode is a very complex task which can't be done by just a single command line.

Comment: Ok but i don't know most of commands can you refer me some sites where i can get this commands

Comment: I've referenced to the documentation in my post.